# What is the best way to pass variables between query and response object field resolver?

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

I need sync way for passing variables between query and response object field resolver.
I know about OperationContext, but it is basic map, so I have some concurrent problems.

```
tmp := "Hello world"
graphql.GetOperationContext(ctx).Variables["HelloWorld"] = &tmp
tmp2 := graphql.GetOperationContext(ctx).Variables["HelloWorld"].(*string)
```

For example my schema

```
Object {
  ID: ID!
  isOK: Boolean! @goField(forceResolver: true)
}

type Query {
  Objects: [Object!]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query resolver should run to completion *before* any field resolver runs. You can attach whatever field(s) you want to the results of the query resolver. These will be available in the `parent` variable of the field resolvers. The extra fields that you add will eventually get stripped out of the final result that is returned to the client.

Comment: Ok, what if this (isOK) field is so big to calculate every query, but also inseparable from the parent object ? 
I don't want to lost my speed if the client did not request this field

Comment: Then you'll want to cache that result.